# why the postback automatically appends the same param to the url?

Tags: asp.net

I have this rewrite rule in my web.config:

```
 <RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>/RecoverPassword.aspx</LookFor>
    <SendTo>/Logon.aspx?t=pr</SendTo>
  </RewriterRule>
```

Well, the first time the user comes on this page all is good. This condition is true:

```
 if (Request.Params["t"] == "pr")
```

I do not understand why, on postback, it automatically appends the same query parameter to the url, so the new url is:

```
http://192.168.1.2/RecoverPassword.aspx?t=pr
```

and now...like you guess the rewritten url will be:

```
/Logon.aspx?t=pr&t=pr
```

I think it's something I forgot to set up in my IIS ..?
On production is working great without this kind of errors...

Can you give me a clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried appendQueryString="false" attribute in the action element of the rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

This one can help avoid double entries in querystring when using urlrewrite:

Add following line to the Page_Load event:

```
Form.Action = Request.RawUrl;
```

Solution originally from: http://forums.asp.net/t/1684316.aspx/